# Angular: A controller with this name is not registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing, angular-controller

I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours now, and I can't seem to find the problem.  I've read some other questions with similar problems, but they don't have any solutions that have worked for me.

I am having trouble registering my controllers.  I am not able to register controllers outside of the file in which I declare the app.  Originally, I set up the 'MainController' in a separate file, which failed.  I was getting an error saying that "The controller with the name 'MainController' is not registered".  Once I put MainController in the same file as the app is declared, there were no problems.  However, when I have a lot of code, I don't want all the controllers in the same file, as it will become too difficult to read.  Here are examples of my code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainController', MainController);
```

I am keeping other controllers in different files, and they are not registering.  For example, in home.controller.js:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('HomeController', HomeController);

function HomeController(HomeService) {

}
```

This controller will not register, and I don't know why.  Each HTML partial in ng-view has its own controller, and the ng-view is within the MainController.  Here is the app.config.js file:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeController as home'
    }).when('/profile', {
      templateUrl: 'views/profile.html',
      controller: 'ProfileController as profile'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

Here is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My App</title>
    <script src="vendors/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.config.js"></script>

    <scripts src="scripts/home.controller.js"></scripts>
    <scripts src="scripts/profile.controller.js"></scripts>

    <script src="scripts/main.service.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/home.service.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/profile.service.js"></script>

    <base href="/" />
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainController as main">
    <header>
      <h1>My App</h1>
    </header>
    <!-- Content varies -->
    <div class="container">
      <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have successfully built projects like this in the past without problem, but I can't find any issue compared to those projects.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you really want to separate your files, I recommend creating modules for each logical piece, ie `angular.module('myApp.home', []).controller('HomeController', ...` and in your main app, `angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'myApp.home', ...`

Comment: Also, your `<base>` tag should be included **before** any `<script>` or `<link>` tags

Comment: I (kind of) replicated your app on Plunker and I'm not seeing the problem you are ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/KpqiWoHbs6KSlIGqkSoA?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

When I've had this issue in the past, it was related to script loading order, especially with using async script loading. You don't appear to be doing that.

To troubleshoot:

Fire a console log statement inside the controller's function body (`console.log('registering controller x')`). This statement will either not show up, or will show up *after* the error.

Angular used to (and I presume it still does) try to wait for app to load and all controllers to register to app before running the code. Either Angular isn't waiting on this controller, or this controller isn't running.

From there, you would verify that the reference to the file is correct (put a console.log at the top of the file), or determine how Angular decides when it believes all controllers are loaded and why it doesn't wait on your controller.

I haven't dealt with Angular since 1.2, because I think it's a pretty bad framework. But that was my experience then, and it seems like the same basic architecture for this. Back then it was relying on Document.ready. I really hope they don't do that anymore (that's where I ran into my async script loader problems).

Best of luck.